# Editing every 3rd line of file in vim

Tags: python, vim

I was making a templated list of methods in vim for a python project. I added lines between each method and wanted to add a `pass` to each method for now-until I implement the method, this will still be interpretable python code. In vim I know how to edit spatially contiguous lines of a file using `:10,17s/<search regex>/<substitute>/` but after doing my edits to add empty lines between methods, I needed to insert the a `pass` every 3rd line. The way I found to do this used pipes and `&` via: 
`:10s/<search regex>/<substitute>|13&|16&` etc. I had maybe 15 of the ampersands chained together to get this to work. Is there a more succint way to get this behaviour in vim?

To address comment, here is a minimal example, in the file myfile.py I have:

```
def _fun1(self):


def _fun2(self):


def _fun3(self):


def _fun4(self):

...etc
```

On the 2nd line, the 5th line, the 8th line, etc. I want to insert `pass` (w/4 spaces before to keep consistent spacings), /i have this up to `_fun15(self):` so would like to get the behavior w/o 14 `|lineNo&`s chained together. Perhaps an incrementing feature w/a variable for the line numbers or some other code that creates the behavior.

Comment: It would be better if you would give us an example of what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Hauleth, thanks for the comment, I posted a code block w/an example of the file I'm looking to edit and how I want to insert `pass` at every 3rd line. Hopefully this makes it clear what I'm trying to do. If not let me know, I'll clarify what is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible way:

```
:g/def _fun/normal! opass
```

- On each line matching `def _fun`…
- open a new line below…
- and insert `pass`.

If you want to have one single line between each stub:

```
:g/def _fun/normal! opass^OJ^Ox
```

- On each line matching `def _fun`…
- open a new line below…
- insert `pass`…
- leave insert mode for a single command…
- join the line below with the current line…
- leave insert mode for a single command…
- and remove that pesky `<Space>`.

Comment: I'd probably do `:g/def .*:\n\n/` to only append `pass` to empty function definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Record a macro

```
qajopass<Esc>jq
```

Now execute it by running `@a` (next time you can use `@@`).

---

As @midor said it can be then used with `:g` command in form of:

```
:g/def _fun\d\+/norm @a
```

To execute this macro on all matching lines.

Comment: The macro is a good idea, but instead of running it manually it would be easier to run it with `:g/`, for example for every line that starts with a `def`

Comment: @midor, the python file is a 1000+ LOC file so I would not want to edit entire file but limit to my line numbers as indicated in the posting.

Answer (score 0):

To put 'pass' with indentation below each function definition I would use:

```
:g/^def/put ='    pass'

^ ........... begining of each line
put ......... puts contents bellow
```

To squeeze blank lines:

```
:g/^$/,/./-1j 

a global command the gets from each empty line ^$
until next non-empty line minus one, performs a join command
```